# Python text to columns

Tags: python, data-analysis

I have been doing a tedious task for a few hrs and have decided to give it a hack with Python. I currently have a dataset with a bunch of columns but in the end,I want only information from every column CELL to be broken up into several others.

```
         Resoultion 
         -1-NO-1-
         -1-NO-1-
         -2-NA-2-
         -3-N-3-
         -4-NA-4-
         -5-NA-5-
         -6-N-6-
         -7--7-
         -8-N-8-
```

I want to break that specific column named resolution into several other columns using.

```
      Output
   1  2  3  4
   No NA N No . . . . . . .
```

Currently, I have tried the following which is outputting a really weird file. Can anyone help me out with this?

```
   x["split"]= mdm_cases_gse['Resolution'].str.split('\n-', expand=True)
```

Comment: is your data originally from a `.txt` file?

Comment: Please explain in more detail how the columns become the output you gave.  I cannot understand why in in the output column 3 is `No` and not `N`.  What would you put in column 7?

Comment: @0TT0 its a csv

Comment: @SethMMorton my mistake just fixed it thanks!